# Print files with specific settings from a web-app

Tags: node.js, windows, printing, usb, google-cloud-print

For a client I’m building a mobile app where users can choose between multiple photo frames. They can add photos to this frames using their mobile devices. When they’re finished the user will be send to a payment screen. When the order is payed the system will create a QR code. With that QR code they can go to one of our physical pillars where they can scan the QR code. A pillar has a computer (Windows 10), a QR scanner and a printer connected (Mitsubishi D90). The system checks the order and starts the print job. For now the pillar computer is running a browser in kiosk mode.

[image]

**The problem**

The frames can have different sizes:

- 5” x 15” x2 (the printer cuts the frame in half, so that you have two
  prints)
- 10” x 15”
- 15” x 10”

When I’m using the native print window everything seems to be working fine. My frames fit on the page perfectly. I can select different page sizes and can make use the internal cutter. However I want to automate this whole process. The system should be able to switch between different sizes and should be able to push a job directly into the queue.

**Approach #1**

Because the computer is running a browser window my first thought was to set up a NodeJS application that can fetch the frame from the server and push a job directly to the queue. I looked into [Node-Printer](https://github.com/tojocky/node-printer). Everything worked like a charm on my Macbook (using CUPS) but unfortunately the pillars are running Windows. I tried to set up everything to work the same way that it did on my Macbook but I couldn’t get the print jobs to process. I received the message that the job was sent to my printer though. I’ve spent multiple days trying to get this to work but node-printer running on Windows has a lot of limitation. I also tried to create a Ubuntu partition to see if it works from there but it resulted in the same problem.

**Approach #2**

My second thought was to setup the printer as a Google Cloud Printer. That way I can push jobs from my web page directly to the Print API. However I discovered a lot limitations when it comes to selecting the same settings as I do using the native print window. On the left the native print window, on the right the google print window.

[image]

I also tried to fetch the printer settings using the [Printer Lookup API](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/simulate.html). I can see a lot of settings (also page sizes) but every time I try to print something the prints just are not the same. The frames are too small, too large, wrongly rotated, strange margins etc. I tried 100 different prints with all possible combination of settings but there was not even one close to what I get when using the native print dialog.

I also tried Electron but I wasn't able to specify any settings. I assume this is also using a node-printer like solution.

I really don’t know where to look anymore or how to fix this. I’ve spent too many days trying to figure out what’s going on. Are there any other (good) approaches I didn’t think of? Is there a way to get the same settings in Google Cloud Print?

TL;DR: Need help to push print jobs in the queue from a browser window (or wrapper like Electron). Could either be through an API like Google Cloud Print or directly USB.

Answer (score 0):

Try Google Cloud Print and give your own settings when u trigger a print.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appInterfaces#submit

Refer to above doc. And when u submit a job add an extra param called "ticket". And specify the media size in the ticket.

And it looks like this:

```
ticket :   {"version":"1.0","print":{"media_size":{"width_microns":210000,"height_microns":297000,"is_continuous_feed":false,"vendor_id":"ISO_A4"}}}
```

(^specify the dimensions you want to print in height and width)

You can find standard dimensions in following pdf under topic 4.2:

http://ftp.pwg.org/pub/pwg/cloud/white/Google_GCP/CDD_2013-11-06.pdf

Try using different combination of height and width for desired results